# How to use Node Server Writing to Firebase from text file to add Strings to a child without a unique key

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database

I have a working node server that uses FS to read from a text file and uploads the Data into separate strings onto Firebase. I am not concerned about security/authentication because this is just a small senior design 'work-around'. My problem is that I made an Android App to read from Firebase and it cannot read the pushed strings from the node server because of an auto generated key. Here's an illustration:

> ```
>    FireBase-Root
>   -> CHILD1
>      ->String1 from manual input
>      ->String2 from manual input
>      ->String3 from manual input 
>      -> AUTO Generated USER KEY 
>         ->String1 pushed from text file
>         ->String2 pushed from txt file
>         ->String3 pushed from text file
> ```

The Android App is able to read the strings from the manual input because it reads CHILD1 directly. I need a way to write to CHILD1 without push so that the auto generated user key does not exist.

I could also change the Android App to implement a USER function to read from the auto generated keys but I would prefer changing the node server

Below is my index.js file which is the node.js server file:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./adminkey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://snaresense.firebaseio.com"
    });

var ref = admin.database().ref('snaresense');

var fs = require("fs");


fs.readFile("received_details.txt", "utf8", function(error, data) {

    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
        }
    StringData = data;  

    var dataArr = data.split(" ");
    console.log(dataArr);

    StringActive = dataArr[0];
    console.log(StringActive);

    StringTrapId = dataArr[1];
    console.log(StringTrapId);

    StringPhoneNum = dataArr[2];
    console.log(StringPhoneNum);

    StringBatteryLevel = dataArr[4];
    console.log(StringBatteryLevel);

    var stringsRef = ref.child('strings');

        stringsRef.push({   
            StringActive,
            StringTrapId,
            StringPhoneNum,
            StringBatteryLevel
        });



});
```

Just to reiterate. Everything works fine. I just need to write these strings to Firebase without PUSH so that the autogenerated key does not exist. Or another solution that allows an Android App to read from the same child directly that this node server writes to.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the 'Index.js' file (or wherever your node server is)

change "push" to "set"

Yup. It's that easy. Wasted so much time of my life.